# How to programatically change LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to create a LinearLayout programmatically and I would want to allow the user to put the number range.
Now it looks like that:

[image]

But when I try to enter more digits eg. 100, 101 or 3,50 it disappears.

[image]

I guess there is not enough space for it to be shown, but I can't figure out what is wrong. Generally I don't want to move + and - buttons when the user enters some values so I guess it should be hardcoded. There would be up to 5-6 digits only, so I need space just for it, but as I said, I can't find the place, where I can change it as my changes either move the entire layout or don't do anything.

Below is my code:

```
LinearLayout horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            LinearLayout titleLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            LinearLayout countLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            ImageButton buttonAdd = new ImageButton(mContext);
            ImageButton buttonSub = new ImageButton(mContext);
            TextView titleTextView = new TextView(mContext);
            EditText countEditText = new EditText(mContext);

            final int[] currentCount = {defaultValue};

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams utilParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            horizontalLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

            utilParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
            titleLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            titleLayout.setPadding(0, pxFromDp(mContext, 16),0, pxFromDp(mContext, 16));
            titleLayout.setLayoutParams(linearLayout);

            countLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            countLayout.setPadding(0, pxFromDp(mContext, 16),0, pxFromDp(mContext, 16));
            countLayout.setLayoutParams(linearLayout);

            utilParams.setMargins(0,0,pxFromDp(mContext, 16f),0);
            titleTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,16);
            titleTextView.setText(title);
            titleTextView.setLayoutParams(utilParams);
            titleLayout.addView(titleTextView);

            utilParams.setMargins(pxFromDp(mContext, 16f),0,pxFromDp(mContext, 16f),0);
            buttonSub.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_remove);
            buttonSub.setLayoutParams(utilParams);
            buttonSub.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.fsm_survey_btn));
            buttonSub.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.fsm_white), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            countLayout.addView(buttonSub);

            countEditText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
            countEditText.setText(String.valueOf(defaultValue));
            countEditText.setLayoutParams(linearLayout);
            countEditText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            countLayout.addView(countEditText);

            buttonAdd.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_24);
            buttonAdd.setLayoutParams(utilParams);
            buttonAdd.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.fsm_survey_btn));
            buttonAdd.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.fsm_white), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            countLayout.addView(buttonAdd);

            horizontalLayout.addView(titleLayout);
            horizontalLayout.addView(countLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding width to the edittext.

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);    countEditText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);`

or add minimum width.
`countEditText.setMinWidth(_width);`